# TextBlock Alignment inside a radiobutton Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button, textblock

I want to create a textbox inside a radiobutton in Windows Phone 7 in order to show multi-line text.

```
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            rb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            rb.Height = 104;
            rb.Width = 396;

            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            txt.Height = 72;
            txt.FontSize = 22;
            txt.Width = 300;
            txt.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            txt.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txt.Text = "Some Text";
            rb.Content = txt;
```

The Problem is that the Text in the Textblock can be either long or short. If it is long , it is fine. But if it is short, it aligns to the top border of the textblock, and it looks ugly. But I can't decrease the height of the textblock, because there will be not enough space in case of 2 or 3 lines of text.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `Height` of the textbox to `double.NaN` in your code like `txt.Height = double.NaN;`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set maxheight

make layout adapts the actual height of textblock by setting right alignment value